# delete duplicate rows based on conditions for other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
ID       | CODE     | DATE
1        | 2398     | 2016-4-3   
1        | null     | 2015-8-3   
2        | 1942     | 2015-9-8   
3        | 6752     | 2013-2-1   
3        | 7217     | 2015-1-1   
4        | 9827     | 2011-2-9
```

there are duplicates in "ID", and I want to drop the duplicates row based on such conditions:

1. If one of the "CODE" contains null, drop the null.
2. If both contains actual code, keep the one with the latest date.
3. If both contains null, keep the one with the latest date.

The desired output looks like this:

```
ID       | CODE     | DATE
1        | 2398     | 2016-4-3     
2        | 1942     | 2015-9-8      
3        | 7217     | 2015-1-1   
4        | 9827     | 2011-2-9
```

I know the way to drop duplicates based on one column:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN ORDER BY COLUMN)
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

But I don't know how to add in my conditions, can someone help?

Comment: Can you have triplicates as well?

Comment: @PM77-1 if there are duplicates for an id, there are only 2

Comment: What happens if there be only one code and it's NULL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Then keep it, I'm just trying to remove duplicates (on "ID"), so conditions only check duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the query below is to compute the following quantity using analytic functions:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) - COUNT(CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
```

This quantity will be equal to one for cases of duplicates having one and only one `NULL` code.  In most other cases, this quantity would be either two (both codes `NULL`), or zero (both codes not `NULL`, or only a single non `NULL` code).

This allows us to determine whether we take the latest record from a single or duplicate, or do we just retain the non `NULL` code from a pair of duplicates.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS total_cnt,
        COUNT(CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) id_cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE
    (total_cnt - id_cnt <> 1 AND rn > 1) OR
    (total_cnt - id_cnt = 1 AND total_cnt > 1 AND CODE IS NULL);
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for replying, can I use WITH on view? I got a syntax error running the first query: "syntax error at end of input"

Comment: I don't know, and I also don't even know if your version of Postgres allows deleting from a CTE.  But, I think my logic is correct, which is the harder part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use the `ORDER BY`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT t.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN
                               ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Code IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),  -- valid codes first
                                         DATE DESC
                              ) as seqnum
     FROM dbo.YourTable t
    )
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

The first row specified by the order by will have a valid code -- if one exists -- and the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

[Postgres does not allow delete on a CTE]

Just start by coding for all three cases:

---

```
DELETE FROM thistable d
WHERE code IS NULL
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM thistable x
        WHERE x.id = d.id AND x.code IS NOT NULL
        )
OR code IS NULL
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM thistable x
        WHERE x.id = d.id AND x.code IS NULL
        AND x.zdate > d.zdate
        )
OR code IS NOT NULL
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM thistable x
        WHERE x.id = d.id AND x.code IS NOT NULL
        AND x.zdate > d.zdate
        );
```

---

Now, you can combine the first two conditions
(and *maybe* even the third)

---

```
DELETE FROM thistable d
WHERE code IS NULL
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM thistable x
        WHERE x.id = d.id
              -- I Don't think you need this
              -- AND x.code <> d.code
        AND x.zdate > d.zdate
        )
OR code IS NOT NULL
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM thistable x
        WHERE x.id = d.id AND x.code IS NOT NULL
        AND x.zdate > d.zdate
        );
```

~